# Inserting date from DataGridView into database?

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

In my application, I have a dataGridview that has a column that gets its data from the database, and it represents a column of type date, there is a button when the user click it, it should insert the current select value of that column in another table that has a column of type date.
I tried doing this that way:

```
 private void btnInesrtDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string date = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].ToString();
            string sql = $"Insert Into BirthDates (Name, DateOfBirth)Values('{txtName.Text}','{date}')";
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
```

but I got an error says:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're using is incorrect, and needs to be fixed. You're currently just specifying some hard-coded values... it can't parse the string literal `'{date}'` to a DateTime.

Use parameters to safely pass values to your query. This is untested, but should work (read the comments too):

```
private void btnInesrtDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "Insert Into BirthDates (Name, DateOfBirth) Values (@Name, @BirthDate)";

    // Always parameterize your query... it's more secure and less prone to errors
    DateTime birthday = Convert.ToDateTime(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BirthDate", birthday);

    conn.Open();

    // Use a Try/Finally block to so the connection is closed even if an exception occurs
    try
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Success");
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it works now. I figured out that I forgot to get the value property before converting to string, but I have a question, Is that mean that the date type in SQL accepts only DateTime object, and cannot accept string? I recall that I did it before!

Answer (score 0):

The query looks incorrect, try removing extra '{' from the query it should be fine if the date format coming from UI is correct. See the code sample below:

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Connection String;");

    string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    string sql = $"Insert Into BirthDates (Name, DateOfBirth)Values('" + txtName.Text + "','" + date +"')";
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
```